# How can I add multiple cities with OpenWeather API to my JavaScript script file?

Tags: javascript

I've just started learning about API's and how to implement them into my JavaScript. I am building a weather app with just HTML, CSS, and JS. I'm currently working on the JS part particularly the API. I have chosen the API call `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}`. I have inserted my key, but I'm confused on what to put as the city name? I do not want to only call one city but have the user use the search bar to enter their own city.
If I put a specific city then I can see the data in the console log. I'm not sure how I can set it to call any city.

I was given some resources: https://openweathermap.force.com/s/article/getting-weather-data-for-any-geo-location-city-name-or-id-2019-10-24-21-47-24

Currently my code looks like :

```
    const res = await fetch (
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid=f6273c080b02e6439d700a66353fe6ed"
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
};
getData();
```

Comment: `const search = document.querySelector(".search");
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

const api = {
 key: "f6273c080b02e6439d700a66353fe6ed",
 base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
}

const getData = async function () {
 const res = await fetch (
 '${api.base}weather?q=${search.value}&appid=${api.key}&units=imperial'
 );
 const data = await res.json();
 console.log(data);
};



btn.addEventListener ("click", function(e){
 event.preventDefault();
 if(event.type == "click" ) {
  getData(search.value);
  console.log(search.value);
 }
 
});`

Comment: So I was able to test it by creating a `search` variable and adding an event listener to the button `btn`. So now when inputing a city name in the search bar the console logs out the city name followed by current weather conditions.